# How to remove negative symbols from negative numbers in batch

Tags: batch-file, random, numbers, echo, symbols

I'm setting up a line of text that will tell if you have lost or gained something, but whenever the value is negative the (-) symbol is always there. I've attempted to search up how to fix this but have not found anything.

```bat
:grocerycomplete
set /a randomsurvivors=%random% %%3 - 1
if %randomsurvivors% LSS 0 (
    set porn=lost
) else (
    set porn=gained
)
echo ========================
echo You have looted the Grocery Store!
echo You have %porn% %randomsurvivors% Survivor(s)!
```

"randomsurvivors" generates a number between 1 and -1.

> The number is then read and if it is <0 it will say lost and if it >0 it will say gained. Whenever it is -1 it will say:

```bat
========================
You have looted the Grocery Store!
You have lost -1 Survivor(s)!
```

I want for it to say:

```bat
========================
You have looted the Grocery Store!
You have lost 1 Survivor(s)!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a very minor change (three chars in the last line) neccessary:

```
:grocerycomplete
set /a randomsurvivors=%random% %%3 - 1
if %randomsurvivors% LSS 0 (
    set porn=lost
) else (
    set porn=gained
)
echo ========================
echo You have looted the Grocery Store!
echo You have %porn% %randomsurvivors:-=% Survivor(s)!
```

using [substring substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) to replace `-` with nothing.